# Convert existing Entity to descendant Entity in Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `class Employee extends Person`. 
Over time an already existing `Person` can become an `Employee` of the company.

I know it's a bad practice to either change the discriminator type using raw SQL or typecasting with obscure PECL extensions.

But is there a design pattern that manages these kind of complication?

Is the only way to clone all the attributes and relationships (Person has many relationships to other entities) to achieve this? How would I go about cloning the existing person with all its relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Person` and `Employee` are two different "things", you should create an Employee entity with a One-to-One relationship with the Person entity. This implies that an Employee is always a Person, but a Person isn't necessarily an Employee.

```
class Employee
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\PersonBundle\Entity\Person", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $person;
}
```

This not only allows you to keep the Person entity with all its existing properties, preventing from having to clone data (which is never a good idea), but most importantly separates the two object types.

As @Zeljko mentioned, you could create a type field field, but I believe that my approach of normalizing the data is a lot cleaner. If you need multiple types of employees, then you could create an EmployeeType table and then have a EmployeeType_ID in the Employee entity. This method is much cleaner than using constants, which tend to get messy and hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks. Initially we had a OneToOne relationship but after refactoring we thought Inheritance sounds more logic. Looks like alltough an Employee extends a Person it doesn't work on this setup where you could change type. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Cloning data is bad idea. Remember: if you are duplicating something, you are doing it wrong :)

I think the best solution is to not use inheritance at all. Just create new column in Person entity called eg. `type` which would be a constant. 
In that entity, put something like this:

```
class Person
{
    const TYPE_USER = 0 ;
    const TYPE_EMPLOYEE = 1 ;
    const TYPE_BIG_FAT_BOSS = 2 ;
    ...

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    protected $type = self::TYPE_USER ;
```

This way you only need to update `type` column and have better functionality.